# require_once fails, but using a non-requested path, when including file from Helper class file

Tags: helper

I have this helper class file (currently reachable):

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/securimage/securimage.php';

class Milyuncarros_Mobile_Helper_Captcha extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function check($value)
    {
        $securimage = new Securimage();
        return $securimage->check($value);
    }

    public function show($ns)
    {
        $img = new Securimage();
        if ($ns) $img->setNamespace($ns);
        $img->show();  // outputs the image and content headers to the browser
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/carros/public_html/includes/src/securimage/securimage.php' (include_path='/home/carros/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/carros/public_html/includes/src/Milyuncarros_Mobile_Helper_Captcha.php on line 3
```

As you can notice, there's no /app directory in the failing path. But my helper class (and the needed securimage folder) is located at /app/code/local/Milyuncarros/Mobile/Helper.

Why is it failing at such wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to compilation enabled. Use the following lines for `require_once`:

```
require_once BP.DS.'securimage'.DS.'securimage.php';
```

`BP` and `DS` are the pre-defined constants in `Mage.php`, `BP` is base path of install while `DS` is directory separator.

Hope this will resolve the issue even if compilation enabled.

Comment: yes, figured it yesterday :). expand the answer (i.e. what values are `BP` and `DS` fetched from).

Comment: Updated the answer on your request.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Mage::getModuleDir('', 'Your_Extension');` and concat Helper. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497441/generic-path-to-a-module-in-magento) to see some more options about folders shortcuts.

Comment: found the error: the helpers are **compiled**, and the compiled files are sent to such "wrong" folder.

Comment: Its a good practice to use this either way since Magento will detect the folders for the includes.